# Solving the heat equation in spherical polars with nonhomogeneous boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

Trying to find the series solution of $r\rho''+2\rho'-\lambda r \rho = f$ with certain ICs & BCs. Question: what is wrong with solution strategy (numerical check does not confirm result).

---

My question:

**What function describes the internal temperature change of a spherical body with some initial temperature profile when its surroundings is heated up?**

---

### Plan

1. Set up equation governing heat transfer
2. Put it into [spherical polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)
3. Set up Initial & Boundary Conditions
4. Obtain two separated equations using separation of variables, [as
   here, in a different setup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Solving_the_heat_equation_using_Fourier_series)
5. Obtain solutions for those: **[THIS IS WHERE IT GOES WRONG]**

   - Temporal one hopefully be a first order ODE, some exponential as solution
   - Spatial one probably will be more complicated, use: series solution
6. Apply IC & BC to fix constants in the general solutions, get final result

---

### Execution

1. $\dot{u} = \alpha \Delta u$, $R \geq r \geq 0$, $R$ being the radius of
   the sphere, $t \geq 0$. Since we expect a spherically symmetric
   solution, $u=u(r,t)$. $u$ it does not depend on $\theta$ & $\phi$.
2. $\dot{u} = \alpha \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial r})$. Since
   $u$ is only a function of $r$ & $t$, we can ignore the $\theta$ & $\phi$ dependence of $\Delta$.
3. - IC: $u(r \leq R,t=0) = f(r)$ (ie initial internal temperature of the spherical object)
   - BC: $u(r=R,t>0) = T_f$ (ie temperature of heated up surroundings
     , heating up taken as instantaneous)
4. Let $u=T(t)\rho(r)$.
   Separated equations:

   - temporal: $T' = \lambda \alpha T$
   - spatial: $r\rho''+2\rho'-\lambda r \rho = 0$ (similarly to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2937298/solving-heat-equation-in-spherical-coordinates) & [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250117/heat-equation-in-spherical-coordinates))
5. Solutions:

   - Temporal: $T(t)=Ae^{\lambda \alpha t}$
   - Spatial:
     let $\rho(r) = \sum_0^{\infty}c_n r^n$. (Not allowing negative powers because we would like to have a real solution at $r=0$ as well.) Substitute this in to the equation for $\rho$:
     $$r\sum_2^{\infty}n(n-1)c_nr^{n-2}+2\sum_1^{\infty}nc_nr^{n-1}-\lambda r\sum_0^{\infty}c_n r^n=0$$
     which is equal to:
     $$\sum_2^{\infty}n(n-1)c_nr^{n-1}+2\sum_1^{\infty}nc_nr^{n-1}-\lambda \sum_0^{\infty}c_n r^{n+1}=0$$
     In the first sum, change every $n$ to $n+2$ & lower the lower limit of summation by 2. In the second sum, change every $n$ to $n+1$ & lower the lower limit of summation by 1. Obtain:
     $$\sum_0^{\infty}(n+2)(n+1)c_{n+2}r^{n+1}+2(n+1)c_{n+1}r^{n}-\lambda c_{n}r^{n+1} = 0$$
     The above equation can only be true if it is true for each powers of $r$. Consider the $r^{n+1}$ terms: $$(n+2)(n+1)c_{n+2} - \lambda c_n = -2(n+2)c_{n+2}$$
     Rearrange:
     $$(n+4)(n+1)c_{n+2}=\lambda c_n$$
     Rewrite:
     $$(n+2)(n-1)c_n = \lambda c_{n-2}$$
     Obtain recurrence relation:
     $$c_n = \frac{\lambda c_{n-2}}{(n+2)(n-1)}$$
     To not to get into trouble with zero division, lets set $c_{-1}$ to $0$, rendering all $c_{n=odd}$ zero. We are free to choose $c_0$, determining all even coefficients.
     Let's plot this & check that we are right!
     Using $c_0=\lambda=1$, computed an approximation to $\rho$ using $c_n$s up to $n=100$. Also computed an approximation to $r\rho''+2\rho'-\lambda r \rho$, which should be zero. (Notebook available [here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/zabop/a120eaadbe50d8249ff92febc63ed21e/untitled164.ipynb), the code is also on the bottom of this post.)
     Unfortunately, it isn't:

*(Note that [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125556/solving-a-heat-equation-in-spherical-coordinates) has a very similar homogeneous equation to mine, but it doesn't use series solutions, but claims that this equation "integrates into" the solution.)*

6. We obtain: $u=T(t,A)\rho(c_0,r)$. Even if my $\rho$ function was
   correct, BC hardly seem satisfiably for general $f$ with these
   constants. Am I missing something? I recall in school (/uni) we
   solved the homogeneous case, when $f$ is $0$, obtained a general
   solution, then changed $f$ to something nonzero, found a particular
   solution, then added the general & the particular solutions. My plan for this:

   - Find orthonormal eigenfunctions $y_n$ & eigenvalues $\sigma_n$ for $Ly_n=\sigma_n y_n$, with $L = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$
   - Fix $T(t=0)=1$, rewrite IC as $rL\rho=r(L\rho_g + L\rho_p) = rL\rho_p = f$, ie $L\rho_p=f/r$ where $\rho_g$ & $\rho_p$ are the general & particular solutions in the $u$, where $u=T(t)\rho(r)=T(t)(\rho_{general}(r)+\rho_{particular}(r))$, $u$ solving $\dot{u} = \alpha \Delta u$.
   - Let $\rho_p=\sum_0^{\infty}s_n y_n$
   - Since $$\langle L\rho_p | y_m \rangle = \langle L\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s_n y_n | y_m \rangle = \langle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s_n L y_n | y_m \rangle = \langle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s_n \sigma_n y_n | y_m \rangle = s_n \sigma_n \langle  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}y_n | y_m \rangle = s_m \sigma_m
     \implies {s_m=\frac{\langle L\rho_p | y_m \rangle}{\sigma_m}},$$ where $\langle f | g \rangle = \int_{all space} f g dV = \int_r=0^{\infty} \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \int_{\phi=0}^{\pi} f(r, \phi, \theta) g(r, \theta, \phi) r^2 \sin(\phi) dr d\phi d\theta$. Therefore, I can compute all $s_n$s, therefore obtain $\rho_p$, giving me a $\rho=\rho_g+\rho_p$, with which I can satisfy the BC & IC: $\rho_g$ will satisfy BC, while $\rho_p$ will satisfy IC.

---

### Question

**What goes wrong in the 5th step of the plan and is the outline for the last, 6th step is correct, or am I missing something?**

---

**The code** (Notebook [here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/zabop/a120eaadbe50d8249ff92febc63ed21e/untitled164.ipynb))

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm

LAMBDA = 1
c1=1
def Cn(n, LAMBDA = LAMBDA, c1=c1):
    if n%2==1:
        return 0
    elif n==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return LAMBDA*Cn(n-2)/ ((n+2)*(n-1))

start=-1
stop=10
step=0.0001
rs = np.arange(start, stop+step, step)

rho = [sum([Cn(n)*(r**n) for n in range(0,100+1)]) for r in tqdm(rs)]

def deriv(arr, dx=step):
    return np.gradient(arr, dx)

rhoderiv = deriv(rho)
rhoderivderiv = deriv(rhoderiv)

this_is_rather_be_zero = [r*rhoderivderiv[i] + 2*rhoderiv[i] - LAMBDA * r * rho[i] for i, r in enumerate(rs)]

plt.plot(rs, rho,c='k',label='rho')
plt.plot(rs, this_is_rather_be_zero,c='g',label='shouldBeZero')
plt.axvline(c='r')
plt.axhline(c='r')
plt.xlim([-1,5])
plt.ylim([-1,5])
plt.legend()
```

Comment: Oh yep, good point! $c_n$s included. I changed the index, but now I am unsure what happens with $c_1$ in the second summation as I simplify $\sum_2^{\infty}n(n-1)c_nr^{n-1}+2\sum_1^{\infty}nc_nr^{n-1}-\lambda r\sum_0^{\infty}c_n r^n=0$ to $\sum_2^{\infty}n(n+1)c_n r^{n-1}-\lambda c_n r^{n+1} = 0$.

Comment: Didn't get the same, edited the question to include what I got, I am looking for what went wrong with my algebra...

Comment: If it is easy for you to check, does mine give the zero?

Comment: For $n$ odd, it does indeed! For $n$ even, it depends on $\lambda$, doesn't it?

Comment: If $c_{n+1} = \lambda c_{n-1}/((n+2)(n+1))$, then $c_{n} = \lambda c_{n-2}/((n+1)n)$, right? - which is the original recurrence relation I've trid, which didn't seem to work numerically.

Comment: OK. sorry but I need to leave, since you're using Jupyter, i think you can solve it using this sympy bit https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/series/formal.html. If not I'll probably be able to check again (and be more patient) in less than 24 hours

Comment: Alright, thank you much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I should apologise for being so careless in the comments. I sent us on a silly hunt for coefficients when you were right the first time. But your code did not implement it correctly (see bottom of answer).

In this answer I only deal with the solving of the ODE in step 5, and the issue of the plot showing that it doesn't solve the equation. It may be a good idea to streamline step 6 into a separate question.

From
$$ r\rho''+2\rho'-\lambda r \rho = 0$$
Substituting in $\rho=\sum_0^\infty c_n r^n$ we get
$$ r\sum_2^\infty n(n-1)c_n r^{n-2}+2\sum_1^\infty n c_nr^{n-1}-\lambda r \sum_0^\infty c_n r^n = 0$$
i.e.
$$ \sum_2^\infty n(n-1)c_n r^{n-1}+2\sum_1^\infty n c_nr^{n-1}-\lambda  \sum_0^\infty c_n r^{n+1} = 0$$
bumping indices by $\pm1$, and defining $c_{-1} := 0$,
$$\sum_1^\infty (n+1)nc_{n+1} r^{n}+2\sum_0^\infty (n+1) c_{n+1}r^{n}-\lambda  \sum_0^\infty c_{n-1} r^{n} = 0$$
Finally, we write $\sum_1^\infty (n+1)nc_{n+1} r^{n} = \sum_0^\infty n(n+1)c_{n+1} r^{n}$ and compare coefficients:
$$(n+1)n c_{n+1} + 2(n+1) c_{n+1} - \lambda c_{n-1} = 0 $$
i.e.
$$(n+1)(n+2) c_{n+1}  - \lambda c_{n-1} = 0. $$
Given initial data $c_{-1}=0$, $c_0$ arbitrary we get $c_{\text{odd}}=0$, and setting $n=2k+1$,
$$ c_{2(k+1)} = \frac{\lambda c_{2k}}{(2k+2)(2k+3)}$$
Staring hard/[Wolfram|Alpha imforms me that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20a%5Bk%2B1%5D%20%3D%20c%20a%5Bk%5D%20%2F%20%28%282k%2B2%29%282k%2B3%29%29) the solution is
$$ c_{2k} = \frac{\lambda^{k}c_0}{\Gamma(2k+2)}= \frac{\lambda^{k}c_0}{(2k+1)!}, $$
so if $\lambda>0$,
$$\rho(r) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{k}c_0}{(2k+1)!}r^{2k}=c_0\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(\sqrt{\lambda}  r)^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}=\frac{c_0}{\sqrt {\lambda} r} \sinh(\sqrt\lambda  r)$$

And this is [indeed](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%20%28sinh%28k%20x%29%2Fkx%29%27%27%20%2B%202%20%28sinh%28k%20x%29%2Fkx%29%27%20-%20k%5E2%20x%20%28sinh%28k%20x%29%2Fkx%29%20) a solution. If $\lambda<0$ then a solution is $\frac1{\sqrt {-\lambda} r} \sin(\sqrt{-\lambda}  r)$. If you allow solutions with $c_{-1}\neq 0$, you get also e.g. $\frac{c_0}{\sqrt {\lambda} r} \cosh(\sqrt\lambda  r)$.

So what went wrong in the plot? You put in the formula for $c_n$ wrong. It should be

```
LAMBDA = 1
c1=1
def Cn(n, LAMBDA = LAMBDA, c1=c1):
    if n%2==1:
        return 0
    elif n==0:
        return c1
    else:
        return LAMBDA*Cn(n-2)/ ((n+1)*(n))
```

instead of `return LAMBDA*Cn(n-2)/ ((n+2)*(n-1))`. This gives e.g. `Cn(2)` as 1/6 as it should, and the plot

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made a description of the whole solution and a visualization accessible here: http://ps738.user.srcf.net/planet.html